# Size of Image after watermarking

Tags: image-manipulation, watermark

I'm curios what happens to the size of the host image after an invisible watermark has been inserted. I'm guessing the size will increase but by how much?

For example, the cover image to be inserted is 1kb and the host image is 2kb. Since your adding additional information the size will be 3kb after the embedding process?

Comment: Depends on the compression algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the algorithm used for inserting the watermark. If the watermark is inserted without any quality loss, it is likely that the file would increase by at least 2KB.

Comment: I'm using DCT and will embed the watermark in the middle band coefficient. The watermark that will be inserted is a gray scale with the size of 123 x 123.